# Data Cleaning using pandas generating key error

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do cleaning my data using csv file and I lookup the code on how to make my data lowercase however when I apply to it get an error. I don't quite sure where is wrong with my coding.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#importing Dataset
df = pd.read_csv('tweet.csv')

#Creating the heatmap
plt.figure(figsize = (8,6))
sb.heatmap(df.isnull(), cbar=False , cmap = 'magma')

#convert all tweet into lowercase
df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(str.lower)
df['tweet'].head()
```

That is my coding and below is the error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3802, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3801 try:
-> 3802     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803 except KeyError as err:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'tweet'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 13
     10 sb.heatmap(df.isnull(), cbar=False , cmap = 'magma')
     12 #convert all tweet into lowercase
---> 13 df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(str.lower)
     14 df['tweet'].head()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3807, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3805 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3806     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3807 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3808 if is_integer(indexer):
   3809     indexer = [indexer]

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3804, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3802     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803 except KeyError as err:
-> 3804     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805 except TypeError:
   3806     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3807     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3808     #  the TypeError.
   3809     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 'tweet'
```

I want to know where my coding wrong and can you show it to me?

Comment: tweet is not a column in your dataframe

Comment: Check for white space around tweet in column header.